# How to get datagridview column's absolute width after using FillWeight?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, datagridview

I want the width of a DataGridView column after using `FillWeight`. Here is my code (C#, VS2015). I am trying to set textBox widths the same as dgv column widths. The last line of the code is my concern:

```
        //Initialise dgv
        //Set column widths for visual appeal
        dgvPRD.Columns["INAME"].FillWeight = 200;
        dgvPRD.Columns["IBATCH"].FillWeight = 150;
        dgvPRD.Columns["DPQTY"].FillWeight = 100;
        dgvPRD.Columns["IPUOMNAME"].FillWeight = 50;
        dgvPRD.Columns["IQTY"].FillWeight = 100;
        dgvPRD.Columns["INOTE"].FillWeight = 300;

        //Initialise textBox locations and sizes
        txtINAME.Left = this.Left + 41; //41 is the RowHeadersWidth of the dgv
        txtINAME.Top = dgvPRD.ColumnHeadersHeight;
        txtINAME.Width = dgvPRD.Columns["INAME"].Width; --> not working (it gives the original column width, before `FillWeight`)
```

Comment: What do you mean by “absolute” width? Did you mean to say “actual” width? Maybe try this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.getpreferredwidth(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thansk @blins, but I dont think it works if autoSizeColumnMode = Fill (which is a pre-requisite to use the FillWeight property).

Comment: I want the actual width after compensating for `FillWeight`. Hence I have used the term `absolute width`. The `.Width` property just gives me the non-compensated width.

Comment: This post has been viewed 16 times, yet no response! Even the trigger-happy downvoters haven't downvoted it, which probably means that this has not been asked before. Is the question so difficult or is it that no one knows the answer?

Comment: Where does this code run? Is the form and DGV loaded/visible when it does?

Comment: Your hint solved my problem @blins ! The code was running in the `public form()` event just after `InitializeComponent();`. I transferred it to the `form_Load` event and it started working! It was so logical - how could it have calculated filled weights if the form wasn't loaded! Thanks a ton! Please reply to this as an answer so that I may mark it as such.